# Fire jQuery on dynamically inserted textstring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a text string and bind it to a `click` event but I can't figure this one out. I want to remove all non-numerical characters inside my `em` element:

```
<div class="cart">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <span class="cartspan">
                <em class="minicart"></em>
                <em id="headercartqty">8 items</em>
            </span>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I use this script to remove it on page load:

```
$('em#headercartqty').text(function(_,xText){
    return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
})
```

My problem is that when I click on a button with the class `.actionbutton` it dynamically updates the string and it then shows the word items again.

How do I bind the script to the button? I understand I should use `.on` somehow? This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".actionbutton", function () {        
        $('em#headercartqty').text(function(_, xText){
            return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah sorry - missed that one - updated the question.

Comment: Have you got any control on the code that dynamically updates the string? (I mean the code that is fired by `.actionbutton`).

Comment: No - unfortunaly not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified` will detect a change to the content, which you can then make your change:-

```
$('em#headercartqty').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  $(this).text(function(_, xText){
      return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
   })
});
```

**UPDATE**

As **@abl**  advised in the comments below:-

> Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop
>   if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.

Maybe try:-

```
function updateQuantity(){
   $(this).text(function(_, xText){
      return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
   })
   $('em#headercartqty').one("DOMSubtreeModified", updateQuantity);
}

$('em#headercartqty').one("DOMSubtreeModified", updateQuantity);
```

Or

```
$('em#headercartqty').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    if(/[^\d]/g.test($(this).text())){
       $(this).text(function(_, xText){
          return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
       })
    }
});
```

Though the first update calls the function twice, where the second calls it 3 times.

Comment: MDN says: [`Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: Yeah - that made my page freeze so not a good solution for me. thanks though!

Comment: @abl true, I guess this will fire twice in this case. maybe use this with `.one` and split the text change to a function and rebind to `.one` after then change.

Comment: It will fire many times (see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AY1Yu4iGcfPgWZPZHtVc?p=info)). You can, however, check first if the text needs to be changed, then call `replace()` only if it does. That will prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: @abl I've added your suggestion :)

Comment: @BG101 just realize today that this freezes IE.. Works on all other browsers though

Answer (score 0):

Your current `$(document).on('click', ".actionbutton", function ()` seems to work properly, so I guess the problem is: *it works too early*.
In other words, when the `.actionbutton` is clicked the two events (the original one which updates content and the yours) are fired, then the yours finishes it work *before the other one*.

So you might try using `setTimeout` to make your own event to delay its work, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".actionbutton", function () {
        setTimeout(function() {     
            $('em#headercartqty').text(function(_, xText){
                return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
            });
        },
        100); // <-- make different tries to adjust delay to the minimum
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('.actionbutton').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var el= $('em#headercartqty');
        el.text(el.text().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')); 
    });

})
```